# Flutter: Selected value doesn't display in the dropdown

Tags: list, flutter, dart, drop-down-menu, sqflite

I'm populating cities name from SQLite database and trying to display as a drop down list. I make it work by following a tutorial, but having a small issue. The selected value is not displayed in dropdown, it keep displaying default hint value. However, I was able to assign and retrieve correct selected value.

**Here is my code:**

`cities.dart`

```
class Cities {
  int id;
  String name;

  Cities(this.id, this.name);

  Cities.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    this.id = json["id"];
    this.name = json["name"];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        'id': null,
        'name': name,
      };
}
```

`Function` that retrieve and returns value from db:

```
Future<List<Cities>> getCitiesList() async {
Database db = await instance.database;

final citiesData = await db.query('cities');

if (citiesData.length == 0) return null;

List<Cities> citiesList = citiesData.map((item) {
  return Cities.fromMap(item);
}).toList();

return citiesList;
}
```

The code which builds drop down, inside `Widget build`:

```
//these are defined above in the code
Cities _city;
final databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.instance;

FutureBuilder<List<Cities>>(

    future: databaseHelper.getCitiesList(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Cities>> snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
      return DropdownButton<Cities>(

        items: snapshot.data
            .map((city) => DropdownMenuItem<Cities>(
                  child: Text(city.name),
                  value: city,
                ))
            .toList(),
        onChanged: (Cities value) {
          setState(() {
            _city = value;
          });
        },
        isExpanded: true,
        // value: _city, //uncommenting this line breaks the layout
        hint: Text('Select City'),
      );
    },
  ),
```

**Error in the console:**

```
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line 620 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null || items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) => item.value == value).length == 1': is not true.
```

Un-commenting this `value: _city,` add same error in display (displays error 8 times, instead of dropdown list).

**Questions:**

1. How can I fix this issue?
2. How can I set default value from the list? (which will be selected by default)

Comment: do you have duplicated cities in `snapshot.data`? if you add `value: _city` when do you have the exception? on the initial load or after changing the selected value?

Comment: Nope, there are no duplicates. Currently, there are only two cities in the list. It happens on both events, initial load + `onChanged`.

Comment: so debug your app by [setting the breakpoint](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/debugging#setting-breakpoints) in the file `dropdown.dart` line #620, and check why the assert fails, i mean why `items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null || items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) => item.value == value).length == 1` is not true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in simple way, just create a simple list of strings and pass that list to dropdown menu.

Here's how:

1. Update your `getCitiesList()` function:

   ```
   Future<List<String>> getCitiesList() async {
     Database db = await instance.database;

     final citiesData = await db.query(tblCities);

     if (citiesData.length == 0) return null;

     return citiesData.map((Map<String, dynamic> row) {
       return row["name"] as String;
     }).toList();
   }
   ```
2. Add this inside your form page:

   ```
   //initialize these at top
   List<String> _citiesList = <String>[];
   String _city;

   void _getCitiesList() async {
     final List<String> _list = await databaseHelper.getCitiesList();
     setState(() {
       _citiesList = _list;
     });
   }
   ```
3. Call `_getCitiesList();` inside `initState()`.
4. Add this inside your `build` method:

   ```
   DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
       child: DropdownButton<String>(
         value: _city,
         items: _citiesList.map((String value) {
           return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
             value: value,
             child: Text(value),
           );
         }).toList(),
         onChanged: (String newValue) {
         setState(() {
             _city = newValue;
         });
         },
   )),
   ```

Comment: I want to store id into my database but I am getting string only so can you help me how can I fetched id and name both.

Comment: @TARUNSHARMA I am not sure but I guess you want to retrieve `id` and `name` both from the DB, if so then it can be done by updating `return` statement of `getCitiesList()` function like this: `return row["id"].toString() + row["name"] as String;`. It will build a `Map` of "ID NAME".