# Flutter: Effective way of inserting list of data in database

Tags: flutter, dart, bulkinsert, sqflite

I have `cities` table and trying to insert city, upon database creation. The table structure is pretty simple, it has just `id` and `name` column.

In `onCreate` method of my database class, I create table with this command:

```
var tblCities = 'cities';
await db.execute('CREATE TABLE $tblCities (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)');
```

I have `Cities` model class with `fromMap` and `toMap` methods.

There are about 350 cities, and I wanted to insert them in the table.

**Q.** What is the best and easy way to do that?

This comes in my mind:

1. creating list of city
2. using `for` loop to iterate entire list
3. creating map of the city using `toMap` method
4. calling `db.insert` method inside the loop

I'm not sure, but this seem dumb approach so thinking about better and optimized solution...

Comment: see https://pub.dev/documentation/sqflite/latest/sqlite_api/DatabaseExecutor/batch.html

Comment: So I should use `rawInsert`? If so then what would I pass it? (`Map` OR `List`)

Comment: no, you can use "normal" `insert`, why would you want to use `rawInsert`?

Comment: I was thinking that maybe `rawInsert` is to insert bulk data.

Comment: thanks @pskink for your help, I was able to make it work by following an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned by @chunhunghan, you can use batch to insert bulk data.

Here's step by step guideline:

1. Get ready your json file e.g `cities.json` (create csv file of data and use csv to json converter like [this](https://www.csvjson.com/csv2json))
2. Add `cities.json` file in your `assets` directory
3. Define it in `pubspec.yaml` like this:

   ```
   assets:
    - assets/cities.json
   ```
4. Paste this code inside `onCreate` method of your database class (make sure its after table creation query)

   ```
   Batch batch = db.batch();

   String citiesJson = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/json/cities.json');
   List citiesList = json.decode(citiesJson);


   citiesList.forEach((val) {
     //assuming you have 'Cities' class defined
     Cities city = Cities.fromMap(val);
     batch.insert(tblCities, city.toMap());
   });

   batch.commit();
   ```

That's it! :)

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, can you please look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58074121/flutter-selected-value-doesnt-display-in-the-dropdown?noredirect=1#comment102544629_58074121)?

Comment: I don't want to use a loop.

Comment: do we need to cast .fromMap followed by .toMap for the insert? Since value from JSON already is a map...?

Answer (score 5):

There is Batch support 
    To avoid ping-pong between dart and native code, you can use Batch:

```
batch = db.batch();
batch.insert('Test', {'name': 'item'});
batch.update('Test', {'name': 'new_item'}, where: 'name = ?', whereArgs: ['item']);
batch.delete('Test', where: 'name = ?', whereArgs: ['item']);
results = await batch.commit();
```

official example https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/example/lib/batch_test_page.dart

In your case, for loop list with batch.insert command, it's easier to maintain 
for simplicity syntax, use toMap, example

```
batch.insert("cities", city.toMap());
```

detail https://www.techiediaries.com/flutter-sqlite-crud-tutorial/

If you prefer rawInsert, please reference [Insert multiple records in Sqflite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56373970/insert-multiple-records-in-sqflite)

Comment: any clue why I hitting this error ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66565018/get-issue-in-select-query

Answer (score -1):

You can write a raw query to insert all the data at once into the database.